# How do we set the Minimum width of a canvas object?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to set minimum width of a canvas object, and don't allow to scale less than it. I can lock it by "lockScalingX" option but I don't want to do it, because after this I can't enlarge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right you cant lock the scaling process because you will not be able to change the size of your objects.

try the `minScaleLimit` property to assign a minimum size , of course it is scale and not size in pixels.

for example.

```
 canvas.item(0).minScaleLimit = 0.5; //scale until the half of the original size.
```

hope helps,
good luck

Comment: Thank you very much Theo, I have already found the solution, You are right, but besides this you must add "lockScalingFlip: true" for the item. This lock the negative scaling.

Comment: is there a way to give min width instead of scale?